# how to redefine section counter in papertex

Tags: numbering, indexing

The package `papertex` includes SECTION NAME in every header. This is not configurable with package arguments I would like to change or eliminate this

Comment: Please provide a compilable document, not just a feature request

Comment: i use papertex class to create newspaper but the section's countair is wrong. how to change or eliminate it

Comment: I asked you to provide a compilable document.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the header just like you change the footer; the command is

```
\heading{<left>}{<center>}{<right>}
```

The standard setting has the section name as `<center>`.

The commands are described at the end of section 3 in the manual of `papertex`.